# Why does this code give EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access

I am working on a game in Cocos2d for iPhone.

In my init method I have an object (type id) declared as follows (also note bossDir is declared as 1):

```
    bossMov = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(75*bossDir, 320-55)];
    [boss runAction:bossMov];
```

Then in a timer method I have:

```
if ([bossMov isDone] == YES) {
    bossDir = -bossDir;
    [boss stopAllActions];
    [boss runAction:bossMov];
}
```

It moves the boss once, but after that it gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS and points me to a line in the file "CCTimer.m" that says:

```
if( elapsed >= interval ) {
    impMethod(target, selector, elapsed); //This line in particular.
    elapsed = 0;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not retaining `bossMov` action. So when you call `[boss stopAllActions];` it is released and deallocated. Then you are trying to run the deallocated action - so you get the bad access.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the NSZombieEnabled because i am not a cocos2d guy but just as a suggestion i am telling you this. Because bad access error comes only when you are pointing to an object which is no longer in the memory and the application crashes if you try to do so

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it really saved me using NSZombie! I had a player instance (NSObject) that was an autorelease object because I had assumed all CCSprite's (cocos2d) and the like also were autorelease, but what I didn't think about was the fact that the cocos2d library stores all CCSprites in arrays, so they're used somewhere meaning they will not be released, but my player instance was immediately released after init, and then the program would crash when my main timer was called. I then changed the player to retain, and release it in my alloc. Thanks a lot again :)